# Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection in azure Db using ssis

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am using azure db and my ssis package is failing with the below error and also the both the source and destination Database are working fine.

we are using sql2012 and our destination is Azure.
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.5058.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  9:31:13 AM  Error: 2014-12-03 09:31:39.32     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: PKG_     Connection manager "Azure_Destination"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "**Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection".**  End Error  Error: 2014-12-03 09:31:39.32     Code: 0xC020801C

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution for my problem . when I have increased the retry count of the SSIS package it is getting success for the second attempt. I did nt get the permanent fix for this but with this temporary fix I can work on .