# Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Get this **Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection issue** while running SQL SSIS package throughout day.Already gone through some of questions posted before as follows:

[Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection in azure Db using ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27421255/7130689), [SSIS: ole db source [55] error 0xC0202009.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083619/ssis-ole-db-source-55-error-0xc0202009), and [SSIS Acquires connection at design time but fails during debug on same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58001223/7130689).

But not able to zeroed on except change timeout setting in SQL connection.

Is this issue related to sql server memory issue,sometimes we get 100% used CPU usage on machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the server hosting SQL Server is under load, such as 100% CPU, SQL Server may not be very responsive to login requests.

See answer from @mrdenny https://serverfault.com/questions/535960/ssis-etl-jobs-fail-with-network-related-errors-when-network-is-ok